# Rename folders in source control level in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I rename all folders in my source control and while I try to check in there is error:

> Cannot rename 'X' because it will have the same name as the item being
>   added or renamed to 'Y'. You must undo the change on 'X', or you must
>   rename 'Y' to a different location.

I try to do as follow but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181398.aspx:

"
You should avoid renaming items under version control using your operating system (for example, using Windows File Explorer, or the rename command in the Windows command prompt). When you have used your operating system to rename an item in in a local workspace, Visual Studio detects the change as two changes: an add and a delete. You can join the two actions into a rename action.

To fix the results of an operating system rename

1.In Visual Studio, in Team Explorer, choose Home icon Home, and then choose Pending Changes.

2.In the Excluded Changes section, choose the Detected changes link.

3.In the Promote Candidate Changes dialog box, select the delete and add actions, open their shortcut menu, and choose Promote as Rename.

4.A single rename change now appears in the Included Changes section. 
"

Answer (score 0):

I read that error as "there is already file/folder Y on the server". Can you check if this is the case using source control explorer or " tf items" ? If this is the case, you need to decide how to resolve this conflict - do you need your rename? Or do you want to rename Y first?